# CPT posts in drop downed in meta box on page doesn't return post ID

Tags: metabox, post-meta, id

I have an issue with displaying ID of selected post. Could you guys help? thanks

Function below

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
function cd_meta_box_add()
{
    add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'My First Meta Box', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'page', 'side', 'high' );
}

function cd_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
        $selected = isset( $values['my_meta_box_select'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['my_meta_box_select'][0] ) : ”;
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_select">Select which case study this logo will link to when it is clicked:<br /><br /></label>
        <select name="my_meta_box_select" id="my_meta_box_select" style="width:100%;">
            <option value="No case study">No case study</option>
                <?php
                $casestudies = array( 'post_type' => 'contact-info', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'asc', 'numberposts' => -1);
                $casestudiesloop = new WP_Query( $casestudies );
                while ( $casestudiesloop->have_posts() ) : $casestudiesloop->the_post();
                    ?> <option value="<?php the_title(); ?>" <?php selected( $selected, get_the_title() ); ?> ><?php the_title(); ?></option>
            <?php
                endwhile;
                    ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_box_nonce" id="meta_box_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'my_meta_box_nonce' ); ?>" />
    <?php
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;

if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_select', esc_attr( $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) );
}
```

So, when I get get_post_meta( $get_post_ID()); it returns

```
array(8) { ["_edit_lock"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "1443437050:2" } ["_edit_last"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } ["_wp_page_template"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "templates/company-vehicles.php" } ["_my_meta_value_key"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "asd" } ["meta-box-text"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["meta-box-dropdown"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" } ["meta-box-checkbox"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "true" } ["my_meta_box_select"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(37) "Dział marketingu i Realizacji Usług" } }
```

"Dział marketingu i Realizacji Usług" is selected element name, but I also need it to return me it's ID, like Dział marketingu i Realizacji Usług->ID.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I am misunderstanding the question but...

> So, when I get `get_post_meta( $get_post_ID());`

... you already have the post ID via `$get_post_ID()` (which is a BuddyPress function I believe) do you not? If so, you are making this far more complicated than it needs to be. `get_post_meta()` is only returning the metadata. Given that you already have the ID in order to use the function, there is no need for it to spit back the ID as well.

Comment: Not really, I'll try to explain it with more details.

I have custom post type with slug "contact-info" which has single posts (with unique IDs).

So on page I display them in meta box and it works pretty ok... when I get get_post_meta( $get_post_ID()); on my template view it var_dumps me array and also selected POST NAME, but what I need to do is get ID of selected post in meta box to filter it by this ID on my template view. 

I hope it's more detailed